# What can i do to make it stop giving me two outputs in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have checked and checked and I cant see why when I type in a word with two consonants it gives me TWO outputs. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class piglatinJethroB {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!");
        System.out.println("Type in a word and I will translate it into pig latin");
        String word = input.next();
        String tolowercase = word.toLowerCase();
        char s = tolowercase.charAt(0);
        char n = tolowercase.charAt(1);
        String sub1 = tolowercase.substring(1);
        String sub2 = tolowercase.substring(2);
        String newword;
        char a = 'a';
        char e = 'e';
        char i = 'i';
        char o = 'o';
        char u = 'u';
        if (s == a || s == e || s == i || s == o || s == u ) {
            newword = tolowercase + "hay";
            System.out.println(newword);
            return;
        } else if (s != a && s != e && s != i && s != o && s != u) {
            newword = sub1 + s + "ay";
            System.out.println(newword);

            if (n != a && n != e && n != i && n != o && n != u) {
                newword = sub2 + s + n + "ay";
                System.out.println(newword);
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If `n` and `s` are both not vowels, it hits two `System.out.println(newword);` — What did you expect?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you’re asking. However, in your  else if you’re printing newword and then if the inner if fires, you’re printing again. Remove both of them and put it after the inner if, as the last part of the else if block.

Comment: So when I type in a word with two consonants into the console it gives me the output for a word that starts with two constants ( and this part is the real trouble ) it also gives me the output for a word that starts with one consonant.
For example:
I type in: stupid
The output: tupidsay, upidstay

Comment: If think it's because you've put an if statement inside the other. So, if 's' is a consonant and 'n' is a consonant too, the two if's are both 'true'

Comment: thanks, I think that was the problem. I am such a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that here:

```
else if (s != a && s != e && s != i && s != o && s != u) {
        newword = sub1 + s + "ay";
        System.out.println(newword);

        if (n != a && n != e && n != i && n != o && n != u) {
            newword = sub2 + s + n + "ay";
            System.out.println(newword);
        }
    }
```

If 's' is a consonant, the 'else if statement' is true. And if 'n' is a consonant the 'if statement' inside the else if statement is also true.
That's why you're are getting two outputs.